# Remove OnDblClick Event on Item using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code attached to an item on a web page:

```
(function(){
  var vName = $("#NAME").substr(2);
  $("#NAME").ondblclick   = new Function("vName+".remove();");
  $("#NAME_2").ondblclick = new Function("processMove();");
})();
```

The code so much is not an issue but what I would like to do, via jQuery is to remove the ability to perform a "ondblclick" on this item, i.e., would like to remove this function or double clicks on this item altogether, only for a particular criteria, which again is not important as part of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just `.unbind()` it:

```
$('selector').unbind('dblclick');
```

Comment: unfortunately didn't work. Tried both dbclick and ondbclick. Is there anyway I can remove this whole (function() I have attached to this item?

Comment: That would return an anonymous instance of the Function prototype (a function)

Comment: Maybe `$('selector').unbind('dblclick')` will only work if `$('selector').bind('dblclick',funtion(){})` is used instead of `ondblclick`.

Comment: Usually you define functions in jQuery like so: `$('selector').dblclick(function() {});`. Try that instead.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your help. Tried what you said Blender and that helped.

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since this thread has been opened but thought I would post my solution.

```
jQuery(function(j$){//This will execute on page load

  $('selector').prop('ondblclick', "");
});
```

This sets the ondblcli