# Internet Explorer 8 delay between pressing the button

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

Need to quickly press a button to +1 to the value.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
   var a = 2;
   function update() {
   document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = a;
   a++;}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="change">1</div>
<input type="button" onclick="update()" value="TEST">
</body>
```

When I click on the button very quickly, there is a delay. For example, a button has been pressed ten times, but value is 6.

In other browsers everything works correctly.

Comment: There's no way for us mere mortals to fix old crappy browsers !

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @squint: His question is "how can I eliminate the delay?"

Comment: I can't duplicate the problem in IE11 at 4-clicks-per-second, but I have seen less-than-ideal click response in the past. Try using onmousedown instead. It has the added benefit of acting immediately, instead of waiting for the mouse button to be released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is definitely a latency issue in Internet Explorer 8. Somewhat in line with what Oscar stated in his answer, the `dblclick` event may be eating up some of the clicks. If this were the case, we could expect that incrementing during that even would eradicate the problem. Sure enough, that's what we find when we handle that event as well.

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    var clicks = 0,
        result = document.getElementsByTagName( "label" )[0],
        button = document.getElementsByTagName( "button" )[0];

    if ( button.addEventListener ) {
        button.addEventListener( "click", increment );
    } else if ( button.attachEvent ) {
        button.attachEvent( "onclick", increment );
        button.attachEvent( "ondblclick", increment );
    }

    function increment () {
        result.innerHTML = ++clicks;
    }

}());
```

The problem doesn't appear to exist with versions of IE that support the `addEventListener` method (Internet Explorer 9 and up). As a result, we really only appear to need the double-binding in version 8 and below.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vapv60jw/1/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problems is an event called "ondblclick" for internet explorer.

You can try the solution from this question to remove that event:

[Remove OnDblClick Event on Item using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452237/remove-ondblclick-event-on-item-using-jquery)